# Matching lines in a text-file with a starting identifer

Tags: c++, file

So I'm a bit stumped on this, I'm reading a file with two types of lines that contain data, and they are started by a number followed by a comma. I need a way in order to match the lines with the same starting digit into a single line and output that. How would I even get started?

Comment: Maybe by giving a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried so far, instead of just asking for help. Someone with your amount of reputation should understand that.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I was not asking for code. I'm sorry if I implied that, I would be content even with a simple psuedo or explanation on how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this by reading each line in two parts: the stuff before the comma, and the stuff after it.

Then I'd have a `map` (or `unordered_map`) with the value before the comma as the key, and the rest as the value associated with it.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> data;

std::string key, value;

while (std::getline(infile, key, ',')) {
    std::getline(infile, value);
    data[key] += value;
}
```

Then (presumably) you'd want to write out the values:

```
for (auto const &v : data)
    std::cout << v.first << ":" << v.second << "\n";
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: I presume you meant `v.second`, not `v.data`?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: Oops--yeah.

Comment: Maps are surprisingly useful.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Just to be sure, this only reads to the first comma, correct?

Comment: @Link: The `getline` in the condition of the `while` loop reads up to the first comma in each line. The `getline` inside the body of the `while` loop reads the remainder of each line. The fact that it is a `while` loop means it repeats until the `getline` in the condition returns something that will convert to `false`, which happens when it can no longer successfully read a string from the file (so overall, it at least attempts to read all the lines in the file).

Comment: Alright, just making sure. Thanks! :)